# Fullcalendar V5 resources (as a function) the fetchInfo.start,end.startStr,endStr.timeZone is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

Below was my options about resources as functions,but fetchInfo.start and end is undefined when it use in ajax.Where is wrong?

```
    refetchResourcesOnNavigate: true,
    resources: function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
        setTimeout(function() { // necessary hack
            var data = 'startDate=' + fetchInfo.start + "&endDate=" + fetchInfo.end + "&joIds=" + $('#joIds').val();
            var opts = {
                handler: '${xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")}',
                data:data,
                dataType: 'json'
            };
            var dataType = opts.dataType ? opts.dataType : 'text';
            var url = APP_ROOT_PATH + '/process/' + SOP_PROJECT + '/CM_Ajax?handler=' + opts.handler;
             $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: data,
                type: 'post',
                dataType: dataType,
                success: function(data) {
                    successCallback(data);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    handleAjaxError(data);
                }
            }); 
        }, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `setTimeout` with 0 milliseconds here? You claim it's some sort of necessary hack but I can't see that it would achieve anything at all. What goes wrong if you don't use that?

Comment: And anyway about these start and end dates...what exactly do you mean by they are undefined "in ajax"? It's unclear what you're describing. Do you mean that those fields are not populated when the server receives the request? I can't see how they could be null when they're being _sent_ ...have you debugged the javascript and looked in the browser's network tool to see precisely what data is sent along with the AJAX request? Please be clear and specific about what is happening.

Comment: P.S. As an aside, for this purpose it may be more sensible to use `fetchInfo.startStr` and `fetchInfo.endStr` instead of the `start` and `end` variables, because those strings are ready-made in unambiguous ISO8601 format, whereas the default output of the JS Date objects when you stringify them is more intended for human readability and is not easily parseable - that could easily be the source of your issue, it would make some sense if your server code could not interpret that output. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resources-function for info.

Comment: I have removed the setTimeout,but it still undefined for startStr and endStr,I have alert them and removed other codes.  var options = {
        refetchResourcesOnNavigate: true,
        resources: function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
  alert(fetchInfo.startStr);
  alert(fetchInfo.endStr);
        }
    }

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem based on the code and data you've provided, sorry. Those values are populated, no problem. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/VwexwRN . What version of fullCalendar are you using? (my test is with the latest version, 5.8)